# Nginx proxy pass url from get argument

Tags: nginx, proxy, proxypass

Let's say I have server `example.com` with nginx.

I want to make a proxy which will proxy pass URL given as part of request URI or GET parameter (it may contain query string).

So e.g. I want nginx to resolve `http://www.google.pl/image.png?x=y` when `GET example.com/proxy/http://www.google.pl/image.png?x=y` request is made.

I've tried sth like this:

```
location /proxy {
    rewrite /proxy(.*) /$1 break;

  resolver 8.8.8.8;
  proxy_pass http://$arg_host/$arg_uri?$query_string;
}
```

Maybe I want redirect? Let's say I want to serve images which are on different server as they are mine (on my domain).

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
location ~ /proxy/(http://.*) {
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    proxy_pass http://$1$is_args$args;
}
```

No explicit rewriting needed. `$is_args` will be set to `?` if the request line has arguments, or an empty string otherwise, and `$args` will contain the parameters in the request (excluding the `?`) or an empty string if there were no query parameters. `$1` will match the part of the URI enclosed in `( ... )` in the location regex.

Comment: if location is like `location /`, and proxy_pass `http://localhost:3000` does `$is_args$args` passed to proxy_pass automatic? Thanks